# Can you tell me proper words in this situation?

Tags: word-request

John: I've found what you're looking for! (Actually, he hasn't found what Jennifer is looking for, that is a lie)

Jennifer: Oh, you've found what I'm looking for. What you've found is very shiny.

In this case, what is the best word for 'to accept something not true as valid.'

Comment: Why would John lie.  Do you mean "John made a mistake".  Why is John trying to deceive Jennifer?

Comment: @James K Because she knows the dog died, she's sad.

Comment: What dog? Actually, is this a dialogue that you made up, or is a quote from somewhere?

Comment: yup, I made it!

Comment: just a typical dog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for some words, applicable when you see something and know it's not really is but you don't want to show your taking notice of it.

If I were you, I would use these words: turn a blind eye to, blink at, or overlook

I like 'turn a blind eye to' or 'wink at/blink at' better than 'overlook' because 'overlook' sounds a little serious or formal to me.

Comment: I haven't heard "blink at" used this way, though it is in the Free Dictionary. I have often heard and seen "wink at" used though.

Comment: "blink at" and "wink at" is the same expression though the frequency of each use would be different from time to time or according to the custom or culture, or habit of the user. But, "you have not heard" doesn't mean it's not used, though I agree with you that "wink at" would have more frequency. "He blinked at her fault."

Comment: To me a wink is voluntary and a blink is usually involuntary. I would naturally think of "blink at"  to be similar to "flinch at". As you said though a lot depends on time, custom and culture. And of course if you flinch or blink at a lie but that's all you do, you are tacitly acceding to it.

Comment: "blink" is okay, but "wink" has a different, almost opposite meaning.  It means that Jennifer is signalling to John that they share a secret.  So she would be telling John that she knows he is lying..........  I also don't see "overlook" as being especially formal, but "turn a blind eye" is a nice phrase to use in speech.